# If I make a new file type for my program, how do I use "Open With" properly?

Tags: windows, explorer, file-extension, open-with, file-type

I made a program.  I also made my own file type, which the program can create, open, and edit.  In Explorer, I right clicked on this new file type and selected "Open With" and chose my program.  Of course, it just opens the program without loading the file.

How do I let my program know that it's being requested to open a file on startup?  Is there some command line argument that "Open With" sends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Windows Explorer sends the path of the file as the command line argument to the executable of your application.

You could use `args[0]` in C# or `argv[1]` in C++ to read it.