# VB.NET Set Default Text Editor

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-explorer

I have created my own text editor in Visual Basic 2013. I want to open text files with it from outside the application: to open them from the Desktop with double click or right click and open with.

I tried to use right click and open with but it doesn't work, it just opens up my application.

How I make my text editor the one that I open text files with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding command line arguments to VB.Net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218217/adding-command-line-arguments-to-vb-net-application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I make a new file type for my program, how do I use "Open With" properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433474/if-i-make-a-new-file-type-for-my-program-how-do-i-use-open-with-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use something like the [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method.

Put this in your form load event:

```
Dim CommandLineArguments() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
If CommandLineArguments.Length >= 2 AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(CommandLineArguments(1)) = False AndAlso IO.File.Exists(CommandLineArguments(1)) Then
    Me.TextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(CommandLineArguments(1))
End If
```

This will get the command line arguments sent to your application (which is the path to the file you are trying to open with your app) and check if the argument is an existing file. If so, it will read all the file's text into your `TextBox`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i get an error. When I use Try statement to catch the error it says "the index is outside of the bounds of the array".
Whats wrong??

Comment: THANK YOU ALOT, I finally got what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @NadhmiKh : Upvote if helpful, and please mark my post as the answer by pressing the green tick on the left of the post.

Answer (score 1):

**Write this code in the form load event.**

```
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

 Dim fname As String = Command$()
        If Not fname = "" Then
            fname = Replace(fname, Chr(34), "")
            Dim obj As New System.IO.StreamReader(fname.ToString)
            RichTextBox1.Rtf = obj.ReadToEnd
            obj.Close()
            Me.Text = "Your Application Name " & fname

        End If

End Sub
```